# Confluent cloud | Java Avro Serialization | junk characters in value

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

I am trying with basic Avro publisher in java which is available in examples

https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.5.1-post/clients/avro/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/clients/basicavro/ProducerExample.java

I was successfully able to publish in self managed confluent cloud in my local machine ( macOS ) and in machine available in GCP ( Self managed confluent binaries )

[image]

**The same was tried it confluent cloud**

I have a confluent cloud access, where i am trying with this same example but it is showing junk characters in value.

[image]

***Steps carried out in confluent cloud***

1. Manually created a topic by name transactions
2. Configuration file was created with following entries
   [image]
3. Ran the java application by passing the absolute file path configuration.
4. I am able to see the schema is also set in confluent cloud.
   [image]

Could any of you help me over here as what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is correct; the Confluent Cloud message viewer doesn't currently (September 2020) support rendering Avro messages.

You can verify that your data is correct by using a consumer such as kafkacat:

```
docker run --rm edenhill/kafkacat:1.6.0 \
         -X security.protocol=SASL_SSL -X sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN \
         -X ssl.ca.location=./etc/ssl/cert.pem -X api.version.request=true \
         -b ${CCLOUD_BROKER_HOST} \
         -X sasl.username="${CCLOUD_API_KEY}" \
         -X sasl.password="${CCLOUD_API_SECRET}" \
         -t your_topic \
         -C -o beginning \
         -f 'Topic %t[%p], offset: %o, Headers: %h, key: %k, payload: %S bytes: %s\n ' \
         -s avro -r https://"${CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_KEY}":"${CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_SECRET}"@${CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Robin Moffatt.  

I have validated the consumer the data looks fine. its only the UI having bug.

Comment: Great - if this is the correct answer then please mark it as Answered as it helps others find it in the future.

Comment: Just did it. pls upvote the question :) 

for the ppl, I did the same exercise on multiple languages and i thought the issue was language dependent and turned out to be a UI bug. 

References :

https://groups.google.com/g/confluent-platform/c/3pSU1TsNg3A/m/7wNWu27UAAAJ
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/issues/780
https://github.com/riferrei/srclient/issues/15

Comment: As of August 2022, it seems the UI is still unable to render AVRO messages.